# how do I link a button inside a movie clip into the mainframe (flash CS6 AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, movieclip

i have made a movie clip with some buttons inside. The idea behind this was to allow a scrolling system to be used. The only problem is i can't seem to figure out how to link a button inside a movie clip with a frame from outside of the movie clip and on the main stage.

My code atm is:

```
stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

sports1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,sport1)

function sport1(e:MouseEvent)

{
    MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(sports)
}
```

What i would like to happen is that each button inside the movie clip will take me to a certain frame on the main stage, like a navigation system. I am really new to flash so i may not understand all the technical terms yet, so be easy on me :)

Comment: `gotoAndStop(sports)` won't work because sports seems to be undefined. Is 'sports' the name of a frameLabel? Try wrapping it in quotations to make it a String.

Comment: Sorry in my code i have used quotations, i get this error message:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at app_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/eScrollDown1()[app_Scene1_fla.MainTimeline::frame5:38] 

I heard this will only work in AS2 :(

Comment: The error is coming from the Main Timeline at frame 5, line 38 in a function called `eScrollDown1()`

Comment: im not sure thats the problem as when i remove the button code, it works completely fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are creating a Main Movie Clip on the Stage and have inner Movie Clips that are acting as buttons. You want those inner buttons to take you to different frames on the main stage when the user interacts with them.

This is how you would do so.

What you would need to do as you already done give the Main Movie clip holding the inner buttons an instance name `sports1` any inner button would also need an instance name say a button has an instance name of `mcButton` to access that button you would need to call on it like so:

```
sports1.mcButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,sport1)
sports1.mcButton.buttonMode = true;
```

then if you want that button when clicked to go to frame 2 on the main stage you would simply do this in the `sport1`function:

```
function sport1(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
      gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

I threw in the `sports1.mcButton.buttonMode = true;` that way it shows that it is interactive ie click able

Comment: Thanks! Flash seems to have a problem with `startScreen.button.buttonMode = true;` line though and when i take it out i get `TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at app_Scene1_fla::MainTimeline/eScrollDown1()[app_Scene1_fla.MainTimeline::frame5:‌​38]`. The thing is when i take all of the button code out the app works fine!

Comment: Sorry the ' startScreen.button.buttonMode = true; ' was supposed to be ' startScreen.mcButton.buttonMode = true; ' My fault. So did this answer help you with your situation?

Comment: Pretty much whatever instance name you give your inner "childs" ie your inner movie clips you have to reference those after you first reference your main movie clip. Not sure if you know about "parent.child"

Comment: I kinda guessed that the button's instance name would replace button, it seems to have a problem with "startScreen" claiming its an undefined property (1120)

`mainCategory_mc.sports1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,sport1);
startScreen.sports1.buttonMode = true;
function sport1(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
      gotoAndStop("sports");
}` This is my code so far. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry again my mistake. I re edited it again. When i was testing the code i was using an instance name startScreen and not your sports1. okay so your using "mainCategory_mc" as your main Movie clip that holds the inner buttons correct? So to make it button mode all you need to do is: mainCategory_mc.sports1.buttonMode = true;

Comment: It's undefined because startScreen wasn't apart of your code.

Comment: `Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 5, Line 71 1119: Access of possibly undefined property buttonMode through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton.` is the new error message :/ it just doesn't want to work which is annoying

Comment: Is there a way to attach a file? i don't mind sending you the file if that is easier for you to correct!

Comment: Yeah send me the file through Email and ill check it out for you. Send to nathanfitchett@hotmail.com